# How do I stop c# from crashing when user input is a string and its supposed to be an integer with int.tryparse?

Tags: c#, string, input, error-handling, integer

I want to learn how to implement the int.tryparse command in my code to prevent the program from crashing with invalid input. This is what I've written so far:

```
using System;

namespace barn_
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int age;
            string a;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How old is the person?");
                age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                a = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                bool v = int.TryParse(a, out age);
                while(a == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
                if (age >= 2 && age <= 5)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.WriteLine("The person has blue clothes.");
                }
                else if (age >= 6 && age <= 9 || age >= 10 && age <= 15)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("The person has red clothes.");
                }
                else if (age < 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The person is too young.");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else if (age > 15)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The person is too old.");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            } while (age < 2 || age > 15);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure it's crashing on the bool v = int.TryParse(a, out age); statement and not the age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());?  Is there an exception written out to the console or to the System's Event Viewer you can post?

Comment: Another issue you have is with the while loop `while(a == true)`... this will never exit. Use try / catch to make sure input is valid.

Comment: `a = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());`
`bool v = int.TryParse(a, out age);`

Why do you need this two lines?

Comment: I'm very confused as to what `a` is even for.. It might help a little if that variable actually had a meaningful name, but even still, I don't get the point. Similar with `v`. Your variables should have descriptive names.

Comment: I have no exceptions in the code. What you see in the post is the code. I need the age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); statement so the user can actually input an integer. It's not crashing on the v = int.TryParse(a, out age); statement as far as I know. It only crashes when the user responds with text or decimal numbers to the question  Console.WriteLine("How old is the person?"); in the console. @spyder1329

Comment: I don't know how to use try/catch statements... As far as I know a while loop should work some way somehow I just can't figure it out. @Jawad

Comment: a = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()); for this line I thought I needed it for the application to be ready in case the user responds with text instead of an integer number to the first question. a also needs to be defined for the tryparse statement to work. As for bool v = int.TryParse(a, out age); I thought I needed this line to convert the string into an integer and then use a boolean variable for the while loop to work... @CarlosSalles

Answer (score 3):

You can *extract a method* to read integer values:

```
private static int ReadInteger(string title, int from, int to) {
  // Keep asking user until some valid input is provided 
  while (true) {
    // If we have a title, print it
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
      Console.WriteLine(title);

    // First we try to parse user input 
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result)) 
      // if parsing succeeds, check for ranges
      if (result >= from && result <= to)
        return result; // result is a valid value in [from..to] range
      else // valid integer, but out of [from..to] range, say, 12345 or -97
        Console.WriteLine($"Value is out of [{from}..{to}] range. Please, try again.");
    else // not a valid integer, say, "bla-bla-bla"
      Console.WriteLine("Not a valid integer value. Please, try again.");
  }
}
```

Then you can use this method as follow:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  // we read and integer, say, in [0..122] range
  // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeanne_Calment
  int age = ReadInteger("How old is the person?", 0, 122);

  // try to order the conditions: when ordered they are more readable 
  if (age < 2)
    Console.WriteLine("The person is too young.");
  else if (age <= 5) {
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    Console.WriteLine("The person has blue clothes.");
  }
  else if (age <= 15) { 
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("The person has red clothes.");
  }
  else
    Console.WriteLine("The person is too old.");
}
```

Comment: This method works really well it's just way to complicated for me to understand everything since I am only 1 month into coding.

Answer (score 0):

With my following answer, I will try to avoid possible bad habits. My code example is probably exaggerated for most use cases, but I would like to clarify a few points and explain the aspects of reusability in object-oriented programming.
However, @Dmitry Bychenko's answer and the comments to your question solve your described problem with a high degree of certainty.

Depending on which IDE you are developing in (e.g. Visual Studio 2019), well-documented methods, which is the case for most system methods such as `int.TryParse` or `Convert.ToInt32`, will show you which exceptions can occur.
For example, with `int.TryParse` no exception can be thrown if no integer is entered. This is different with `Convert.ToInt32`. If you try to convert a string that is not an integer with `Convert.ToInt32`, the exception `FormatException` is thrown, indicating that the part to be converted is not an integer.

Now to the code example and reusability.
The following two code snippets of your example are very similar. This can mostly be deduced from the fact that a method can be generated out of them. In Visual Studio 2019, automatically generated method can be created with "Ctrl + R + M".

```cs
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.WriteLine("The person has blue clothes.");
```

```cs
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine("The person has red clothes.");
```

In later code example this method is found with the name "PrintTextInConsoleInColor". The good reason for using a method is that the colour is set and a text is printed. This pattern repeats itself. If you want to output a sound every time the colour is set, you have to change EVERY part where the code occurs. This is very bad and involves a lot of effort and even inconsistency. This is very serious and time consuming for larger projects, which is of course the case for more complex processes than setting a colour and playing a sound, which is just for demo.

The naming of methods also plays an important role.  One has to think that it is not only console input. That's why the name "GetIntegerFromConsoleInput" is exaggerated in the context of a pure console application, although it should always be clear from the name of a method what is happening inside or when invoking it, so that you are not suddenly surprised when it is executed.

In terms of reusability, it makes sense to split the logic you want into several parts, such as "GetIntegerFromConsoleInput" and "GetIntegerInRangeFromConsoleInput". The reason for this is that if you need ONLY one number, the method "GetIntegerFromConsoleInput" can be used. However, if you require a number within a range, as in your case, "GetIntegerInRangeFromConsoleInput" will be used.
If you now look at the documentation of the method, you can see the documentation of the exception, which is also applied by an IDE like "Visual Studio".
Basically, it is also recommended to avoid nesting "if-statements" and "loops", as this strongly affects the readability of the code.
In the Console, an empty line can be inserted by a control character, which saves you the multiple use of "Console.WriteLine("")".

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Hello\nWorld");
```

Finally, a potential solution for writing a class for ConsoleIO and how it can be reused.

```cs
public class ConsoleIOHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get console input within range.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lowerBoundary"> Lower boundary included in Range.</param>
    /// <param name="upperBoundary"> Upper boundary included in Range.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">Thrown in case the lower boundary is greater than the upper boundary.</exception>
    public int GetIntegerInRangeFromConsoleInput(int lowerBoundary, int upperBoundary)
    {
        if (lowerBoundary >= upperBoundary)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(lowerBoundary), "Lower boundary has to be lower than upper boundary!");
        }

        int result;
        bool isInRange;

        do
        {
            result = GetIntegerFromConsoleInput();
            isInRange = IsInBoundaries(result, lowerBoundary, upperBoundary);

            if (!isInRange)
            {
                PrintTextInConsoleInColor($"Input {result} is not within boundaries of {lowerBoundary} and {upperBoundary}", ConsoleColor.Red);
            }
        }
        while (!isInRange);

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get interger from console input.
    /// </summary>
    public int GetIntegerFromConsoleInput()
    {
        bool isInteger;
        int result;

        do
        {
            isInteger = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);

            if (!isInteger)
            {
                PrintTextInConsoleInColor("Input is not a number!", ConsoleColor.Red);
            }
        }
        while (!isInteger);

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks weather a input number is within lower and upper boundary.
    /// </summary>
    private bool IsInBoundaries(int input, int lowerBoundary, int upperBoundary)
    {
        return input >= lowerBoundary && input <= upperBoundary;
    }

    private void PrintTextInConsoleInColor(string message, ConsoleColor consoleColor)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = consoleColor;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

I hope that I have been able to bring more clarity to your question, even if I have deviated greatly from the actual question. I apologise in case I have described things that were already known, I just wanted to use the example to point out things that struck me.